# XMLListCollection find index value

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to find specific value on a XMLListCollection.

I try to use something like this but it doesn't work!

```
var xmllisteRDV:XMLList= XML(event.result).RDVClinik;
xmlCollSuivi = new XMLListCollection(xmllisteRDV);
var index:Number = -1;
for(var i:Number = 0; i < xmllisteRDV.length(); i++)
{
    if(XML(xmllisteRDV[i]).@grDateDeb == todayDate)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First going to try pointing out errors in the original code:

```
var xmllisteRDV:XMLList= XML(event.result).RDVClinik;  //Unnecessary cast, event.result is Object compiler will not check or know the run-time type, doesn't care because Object is declared dynamic meaning properties can be added to it dynamically, if RDVClinik didn't exist on the particular Object type it would simply be null casting as XML gives it no information about this "property"
xmlCollSuivi = new XMLListCollection(xmllisteRDV);
 var index:Number = -1;
        for(var i:Number = 0; i < xmllisteRDV.length(); i++) //length is a property not a method on XMLListCollection this should throw a compile time error
        {
            if(XML(xmllisteRDV[i]).@grDateDeb == todayDate)// I see no type when debugging for the result of xmllisteRDV[i] not positive here but this cast is at the least unnecessary
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Here's a version I think will work possibly with changes to how todayDate is built

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var todayDate:String = date.dateUTC+"/"+date.dayUTC+"/"+date.fullYear;
var index:int=-1;
for(var i:int = 0; i < flex3Projects.length; i++)
{
    trace(xmllisteRDV[i].@grDateDeb)
    if(xmllisteRDV[i].@grDateDeb.toString() == todayDate)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With you help, I found the solution

```
private function setSelectedItem():void
{
    var gData:Object = dgSuiviClini.dataProvider;
    var todayDate:String= new DateUtility().DateAsToString(new Date());

    for(var i:Number=0; i < gData.length; i++)
    {
        var thisObj:Object = gData.getItemAt(i);
        if(thisObj.grDateDeb == todayDate)
        {
            dgSuiviClini.selectedIndex = i;
            //sometimes scrollToIndex doesnt work if validateNow() not done
            dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
                //dgSuiviClini.scrollToIndex(i);
        }
        else{
            dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
                // dgSuiviClini.scrollToIndex(gData.length);


        }
    }
    dgSuiviClini.validateNow();
    dgSuiviClini.editedItemPosition = { rowIndex: gData.length-1, columnIndex: nColSaisie };


}
```

Thanks